# How can I insert a custom datetime into sql via python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to insert a custom datetime string into my maria db. I have a code like this:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx", user="xxx", passwd="xxx", db="xxx")

cur = db.cursor()


cur.execute("INSERT INTO `xxx` (`ID`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', %s)" % ('2021-07-01 00:00:00'))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

My maria db is about two columns:

1. `id`, which is of type `int`, primary key
2. `datetime`, which is of type `datetime` and by default 0

I am running the script on my Raspberry Pi.

After running this Python code, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "datenbank.py", line 8, in 
> cur.execute("INSERT INTO `datetime` (`id`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', %s)" % ('2021-07-01 00:00:00'))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
> self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
> raise errorvalue
>
> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00)' at line 1")

How can I insert a custom datetime into my db?

Comment: check mariadb version. I think there is syntax issue. Try cursor.execute(Query1,"anyvalue that will be passed")

Answer (score 0):

After the `%` string formatting operator is applied, the resulting string being passed to `cur.execute` is:

```
"INSERT INTO `xxx` (`ID`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', 2021-07-01 00:00:00)"
```

But you need:

```
"INSERT INTO `xxx` (`ID`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', '2021-07-01 00:00:00')"
```

So start with:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `xxx` (`ID`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', '%s')" % ('2021-07-01 00:00:00'))
```

Better yet, don't use the `%` string formatting operator at all. Instead, use a prepared statement where `%s` represents a parameter to be replaced by the `MySQLdb` driver and the actual parameter values are provided as a second argument as either a list or tuple:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `xxx` (`ID`, `datetime`) VALUES ('1', %s)", ('2021-07-01 00:00:00',))
```

Using prepared statements will prevent SQL Injection attacks that are possible when the values are being provided from outside sources.